# Overwrite css variables

Tags: css, css-variables

I have a component that declares and use a css variable "--test: red"

But I want to re-declare this variable with a new color outside this component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-va9k9q?file=style.css

Is this rule right?

```
:root *{
  --test: green;
}
```

Why * is required? If I remove this, it doesn't work

```
:root *{
  --test: green;
}
#app {
  --test: red;
}
#app h1{
  background-color: var(--test);
}
```

Html

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="app"><h1>Example</h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The final result must have a green background-color

Answer (score 2):

Use a second variable in case you want to only consider `:root`

```css
:root {
  --new: green;
}

#app {
  --test: red;
}

#app h1 {
  background-color: var(--new, var(--test)); /* will fallback to "test" if "new" is not defined */
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>Example</h1>
</div>
```

Or you keep using the code you show which is correct since you will target all the elements (with `*`) to set the variable `--test` that will get used instead of the one inherited from `#app`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is about **ordering and priority** of css selectors

if you do like this:

```
:root {
  --test: red;
}

.
.
.

:root {
  --test: green;
}
```

the second selector have more priority

but if you do:

```
:root #app{
  --test: green;
}

.
.
.

:root {
  --test: red;
}
```

the first selector will apply for #app.
if another block is defined outside of #app, it would get red color.

:root * {} works because it have **more priority.**

read more about priority in [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)